# Rails: Match new (string) IP address to Array of wildcard IP Addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, match

How would you construct the regex for a string match of some Banned IPs list containing wildcards (192.168.1.*) to some new IP address in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regexp#union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union). Something like this:

```
ips = %w(192.168.1.* *.0.0.0 127.0.0.1)
re = Regexp.union(ips.map { |i| Regexp.new(i.gsub('*', '\d+')) })

'192.168.1.2' =~ re
```